# my new exhaust bathroom fan wiring issue

Tags: wiring, exhaust-fan

The fan unit itself has a black wire, a white wire, and 2 green/yellow wires. Where do I tie in the green/yellow wires?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the box you're wiring the fan to?

Comment: fan is getting wired directly to a 14/2 wire. The standard black, white, and ground. But its the fan unit itself that has a black, white, and the 2 green yellow wires

Answer (score 1):

Green/Yellow is typically the bonding conductors (ground).  The reason there are two of them is because one bonds the fan enclosure, the the other one bonds the electrical enclosure.  Tie them to the ground wire of the cable you used to power the fan.